# What does "which" refer to if there are two subjects?

Tags: grammar

> 1. Alaska is one of the states of America which is located on the border side.

> 2. Alaska is one of the states of America which is a superpower country.

In the first sentence *"which"* refers to Alaska.

In the second sentence *"which"* refers to America.

Which sentence is wrong?

Comment: #2 also refers to Alaska without a comma after America

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where the distinction between restrictive and nonrestrictive clauses comes into picture.

The proper way to write 1) is:

> Alaska is one of the states of America which/that is located on the border side.

Note the absence of comma above: the restrictive relative clause *which/that is located on the border side* is essential, because it provides necessary information about Alaska.

Likewise, 2) should be written as:

> Alaska is one of the states of America, which is a superpower country.

Here you need a comma after America, and the following nonrestrictive relative clause *which is a superpower* merely adds extra information about America. You could do away with this parenthetical part. Note also that in this case you must only use *which.*

Comment: Please check for readily predictable duplicates before answering.